# PARTIAL AND EXACT MATCH word search in solr

Tags: solr

word search in solr example:(IN 3 DOCS ) SACHIN ANNA, SACHIN DEV,SACHIN BHAV...

I am searching 1st word ie SACHIN, It is displaying all 3 results,SACHIN ANNA, SACHIN DEV,SACHIN BHAV.

but when im searching particularly for SACHIN ANNA,even this time it is displaying all the 3 results. I want only the particular result. how to do. I am using this tokenizer in index

```
<tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" />
```

Comment: would be more clear if you could add more details.. like your configs

Comment: Are the order of the results right?

Comment: Can you post your schema solrconfig and what query you are firing ?

Answer (score -1):

Try searching with double quotes i.e "SACHIN ANNA"

you can go through the following links incase if you missed them

http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters

Comment: i think @sarvesh needs to change the analyzer for that field, personally i would recommend using a string field, but the config that was provided was too short to make a comment, and also does that field needs to provide both partial and full matching? or only one of them required? if both of them are required then those values can be stored in different fields and query could be built according to that

Comment: Hmmm did you try few more searches like "ANNA","DEV" kindof